# Using custom infopath form in workflow

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

I am trying to create the following workflow. The workflow part is not a problem but I don't know how can I show my own form in Step 2 mentioned below.

SharePoint and Infopath is 2013 while workflow being created in SPD 2013 is of type 2010.

Workflow

1. A user submits his info like name and phone
2. Workflow is set to start automatically
3. In next step manager of that user submits his info like manager name and manager phone
4. Workflow stops

So how it goes is:

- There is a list called YourInfo which has two fields YourName and YourPhone
- User1 comes and inserts a new item in this list. Workflow automatically starts.
- In next step User2 comes which is shown a form with fields ManagerName and ManagerPhone (now these fields can be part of original YourInfo list or we can create a new one I am not sure which is better)
- User2 submits this info which is saved in list. Workflow stops.

How can I show that form in browser to User2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible approach

**First approach**

> You can have two views one which takes the inputs for your info and
>   once these details are filled by the employee and submitted, have a
>   flag to identify the data submission. Then switch to the second view
>   when the manager opens the form.

**Second approach**

> Have two lists, your info and your managers info. Once your info is
>   submitted, create a item in managers info from workflow with the look
>   up to your info. Have the manager fill rest of the details.